# Changing post parameters of form on submit without it being visible to the user

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

I have following piece of code:

```
   <h:form >
       <h:inputText  value="#{bean.property}"/><br/>
       <h:commandButton
           value="Send"
           action="#{bean.action}"/>
   </h:form>
```

How do I (without jQuery) change the value of property from inputText in post form when someone clicks the button without it being visible to the user? Let's say that I know the inputTexts name in generated html and it is for example

```
<input type="text" name="inputName" />
```

My try is

```
   document.forms['formName'].onsubmit = function(){
       var txt = document.getElementsByName("inputName")[0];
       txt.value = "changed"
       documents.forms['formName'].submit();
   }
```

But this changes what is in inputText and it's clearly visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hidden input field to the form. In the OnSubmit event handler, set that field to whatever value you want. Have the backend ignore the field that's visible to the user and only use the hidden one (you can accomplish that via how you name the fields).